# I have two issues with a sub form

Tags: vba, ms-access

First the layout. All forms are unbound.
I have a main form that collects inspection, client, and location data. Once that is added they select cmd button to open a subform for adding the weld information. In this sub form I have a combobox that when they select a certain disposition it makes the third subform visible. This sub form is in datasheet view to add defects to the weld_id.
Tables. tbl_1 is for the inspection form (main form). tbl-2 is the weld data. They have a join table. tbl_3 is a defect table with a join table for tbl_2 and tbl_3. This join table has an autoID, weld_id, defect_id, and defect_qty (txtbox).
The forms work fine except that sfrm_2 (datasheet view) will not allow me to enter more than one row of data.

My biggest problem comes with the insert on sfrm_1 weld data. When I execute the cmd button it will insert everything correctly in tbl_2 and will insert the tbl_2 @@identity into the tbl_2/tbl_3 join table. It will not insert the defect_id and txtbox value (defect_qty) into the join table. I've tried so many different ways and I'm at a loss. I've run debuggers, and no matter what I do, I get a object required error. Everything is named correctly and present.

I am thinking it has to be with the cbobox. Although the code is looking at the defect_id in the box it just refuses to insert.

Access version is whatever the latest is in office 360. I know some coding can vary from different versions.

I even dropped the code in ChatGPT to see if it could locate the missing code and it came back saying "it looks like you're" and described exactly what I want, and said it should be working fine. Maybe y'all can see what is wrong here or maybe it's somewhere in the properties of the forms?

Another thing I am wondering is if I should build a query for the sfrm_2. If that would make things work better? But that would bind the form to the query would it not? maybe for this purpose that wouldn't cause future issues with expansion of the database.

**EDIT** I was looking again, and Im wondering. Do I need to add a "dim defectID as long"
then "defectID = Nz(me.cbo_defect_id, 0)"?

Here is the VBA. Hopefully someone sees what I'm missing in this.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Me.defects.Visible = False

End Sub


Private Sub cbo_disposition_Change()
   If cbo_disposition <> "Accept" Then
      Me.defects.Visible = True
   Else
      Me.defects.Visible = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmd_insert_weld_Click()


    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsWeld As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsWeldDefectJoin As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim weldID As Long
  
    Dim dispositionID As Long
      dispositionID = Nz(Me.cbo_disposition, 0)
      'if dispo id is not found, exit function
      If dispositionID = 0 Then
         MsgBox "disposition not selected. Please enter disposition.", vbExclamation, "Error"
         Exit Sub
      End If
  
    ' Insert weld table data and retrieve the auto-generated weld_id
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_welds (weld_no, disposition_id, comments) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & Me.txt_weld_no & "', '" & dispositionID & "', '" & Me.txt_comments &      "');"
    db.Execute strSQL
    strSQL = "SELECT @@Identity AS LastWeldID;"
    Set rsWeld = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    weldID = rsWeld!LastWeldID
    rsWeld.Close
    Set rsWeld = Nothing

    ' Insert records into WeldDefectJoin for selected defects
    If disposition_id <> 1 Then
        Set rsWeldDefectJoin = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_weld_defect_join")
        *****For Each row In Me.defects.Form.Recordset  <----this is what the debug highlights as missing object*****
            If row("defect_id") = True Then
                ' Add a record to WeldDefectJoin for each selected defect
                rsWeldDefectJoin.AddNew
                rsWeldDefectJoin!weld_id = weldID
                rsWeldDefectJoin!defect_id = row("defect_id")
                rsWeldDefectJoin!defect_qty = row("defect_qty")
                rsWeldDefectJoin.Update
            End If
        Next
        rsWeldDefectJoin.Close
        Set rsWeldDefectJoin = Nothing
    End If

    ' Reset form elements
    Set db = Nothing
    Me.txt_weld_no = ""
    Me.cbo_disposition = Null
    Me.txt_comments = ""
    Me.defects.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: What is **row**? It is not declared nor set. If forms are UNBOUND, then there is no form Recordset to reference and no "rows". If you need to save data from UNBOUND form and UNBOUND controls, then reference controls, not Recordset.

Comment: Not surprising that an UNBOUND form in datasheet view will not allow more than one row input. There is no recordset associated with this form.  There is no place for the input to go.  There is no record navigation. Why are you using UNBOUND forms and creating all this work for yourself instead of letting Access do the heavy lifting?

Comment: row was what chatGPT offered to try and bind the controls. The code I provided was like iteration number 12.

Answer (score 1):

If forms are UNBOUND, then there is no form Recordset to reference and no "rows". If you need to save data from UNBOUND form and UNBOUND controls, then reference controls, not a non-existing Recordset. This means looping through controls on form. Options:

1. loop through all controls with conditions to determine if control is type with data (Tag property can be useful for this) - many examples on web of this approach
2. loop specific controls by name - if naming is like: cbxDID1, tbxQty1, cbxDID2, tbxQty2, etc, code can dynamically build control name in loop with iteration variable

Example for option 2 - say you have 10 "rows" of controls, consider:

```
For x = 1 to 10
    rsWeldDefectJoin.AddNew
    rsWeldDefectJoin!weld_id = weldID
    rsWeldDefectJoin!defect_id = Me("cbxDID" & x)
    rsWeldDefectJoin!defect_qty = Me("tbxQty" & x)
    rsWeldDefectJoin.Update
Next
```

Expand this code to test if control has data before creating record.